# Scala: Given a scala.xml.Node, what's the most efficient way of getting the second (or n-th) child element?

Tags: xml, scala

Given a `scala.xml.Node` object (with white space and elements as child nodes) what's the most efficient way of getting the second (or n-th) child element?

Usually I would go for the built-in `(node \ "foo")`, but sometimes I have to rely on the position of the element. For example, I could have two Choice groups that could be either `foo` or `bar`. The document could be

```
<something>
  <foo/>
  <foo/>
</something>
```

or

```
<something>
  <foo/>
  <bar/>
</something>
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like retronym's `drop(n).headOption` pattern as it accounts for when you have less children than `n`. But I think you meant the second child node (excluding text nodes), not the second instance of the `<foo>` tag. With that in mind, combining with your answer or using `partialMap`:

```
node.child.partialMap{case x:scala.xml.Elem => x}.drop(n).headOption

node.child.filter(_.isInstanceOf[scala.xml.Elem]).drop(n).headOption
```

This has to assume that you won't want to extract *text* in:

```
val node = <something><foo/>text</something>
```

Efficiency wise, the only other thing I could think of is to make filter lazy if you wanted to retrieve the second child when there are a large number of children. I think this may be achieved by running filter on `node.child.iterator` instead.

**Edit:** 
Changed `toIterable` to `iterator`.
good point, calling `drop(n)` on an `ArrayBuffer` will cause additional allocations, also how many is hard to tell, since it seems `drop` is overridden in `IndexSeqLike`. But using the iterator would address that too. So for large number of children:

```
node.child.iterator.filter(_.isInstanceOf[scala.xml.Elem]).drop(n).next
```

If you want to have it be safe, you may need to define a function to check for `hasNext`.

*All of this is tested only in 2.8.*

Comment: So drop(n).headOption buys me safety, but not efficiency? Since child returns ArrayBuffer, making it iterable avoids filtering cost only, right?

Answer (score 2):

Get the second element named "foo", or `None` if not found:

```
(xml \ "foo").drop(1).headOption
```

Or, more efficiently in case of large XML structures:

```
xml.child.toStream.partialMap { 
   case e: xml.Elem if e.label == "foo" => e
}.drop(1).headOption
```

(This is with Scala 2.8)

**UPDATE**

To get the second, regardless of name:

```
 (xml \ "_") drop(1) headOption
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for clarification, as @huynhjl wrote, I am interested in the second child element, not the second instance of foo.

Answer (score 1):

What I have so far is:

```
node.child.filter(_.isInstanceOf[scala.xml.Elem])(1)
```